# Error de identacion

Tags: python

Me salta un error de identación. Este es mi código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self,username, password):
            self.username=username
            self.password = password
            self.bot=webdriver.Firefox()


    def login(self):
            bot=self.bot  
            bot.get("https://twitter.com")
            time.sleep(3)
            email=bot.find_element_by_class_name("email-input")
            password=bot.find_element_by_name("session[password]")
            email.clear()
            password.clear()
            email.send_keys(self.username)
            password.send_keys(self.password)

Alex = TwitterBot("xxxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com", "xxxxxx")
Alex.login()
```

Comment: ¿En qué línea te da el error? Verifica que todas las líneas hayan sido indentadas usando el mismo método (espacios, o tabuladores, no mezclas)

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el script en un servicio de compartición de archivos tipo mega, drive, etc? Es importante saber el contenido EXACTO del archivo para saber si hay espacios o tabuladores en todos los sitios. Es probable que al copiar/pegar hayas convertido tabuladores en espacios y se esté ocultando el problema subyacente.

Comment: Un consejo que puede servirte, al menos a mi me sirve. luego de cada `:` apretar `enter` . Por ejemplo `def fx(a):` (enter)

Comment: Alejandro, ¿podrías compartirnos el código original como te indiqué? Yo consigo ejecutar tu código sin ningún problema, por lo que es probable que al copiar/pegar el código a stackoverflow hayas cambiado sutilmente algo que es lo que impedía la ejecución del código.

Answer (score 1):

Siempre deberias de usar 4 espacios. 
Te invito a leer la documentación, para que tengas un poco más claro cómo debe funcionar:https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self,username, password):
        self.username=username
        self.password = password
        self.bot=webdriver.Firefox()

    def login(self):
        bot=self.bot  
        bot.get("https://twitter.com")
        time.sleep(3)
        email=bot.find_element_by_class_name("email-input")
        password=bot.find_element_by_name("session[password]")
        email.clear()
        password.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        password.send_keys(self.password)

Alex = TwitterBot("xxxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com", "xxxxxx")
Alex.login()
```

Answer (score 0):

te comparto un truco que yo uso cuando tengo problemas con la indentación:

1. Dentro del archivo con tu código presiona CTRL + F para que te aparezca el buscador.
2. Presiona 4 veces la barra espaciadora, para que así, te muestre dónde hay indentación con 4 espacios.
3. Fijate en los lugares a la izquierda del código que no están sombreados, en esos lugares hay tabulación, entonces borras la tabulación y pones 4 espacios.

[image: Imagen para mostrar el ejemplo de solución para el problema de indentación]

Espero que sea de ayuda, suerte!